# Laravel pagination keep hash

Tags: jquery, ajax, hash, pagination, laravel-5

My url looks like

```
domain.com/images#style=2
```

The hash is there so a user can filter options without a page refresh and still be able to use the back button for previous search result.

When I generate pagination with ajax and go to the page the hash '#style=2' gets removed. How can I keep the hash part?

Answer (score 0):

In laravel the `->withQueryString()` doesn't work for keeping the hash in the URL.
You should use the [`->fragment()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#appending-hash-fragments) after your `->paginate()` method.

**Example:**

```
User::with('posts')
    ->paginate()
    ->withQueryString()
    ->fragment('style');
```